# How to generate BlockingStub in C++ in Protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following `.proto` for `Protobuf` 2.6.1:

```java
service InstallService {
    rpc getWifiNetworks (WifiRequest) returns (WifiResponse);
}
```

I've generated Java files and I'm having BlockingStub:

```java
TestInstallService.BlockingInterface service = TestInstallService.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

and I can use it in a blocking way (works well):

```java
Wifi.WifiResponse response = service.getWifiNetworks(controller, request);
```

Now I'm creating a C++ client which should work in a blocking way too but I can't see any `Blocking` interfaces either in proto or in generated C++ code. How to generate `BlockingStub` in C++ in Protobuf? How can I pass closure if working in an async way?

Generated C++ service file (`.cpp`):

```cpp
class InstallService_Stub;

class InstallService : public ::google::protobuf::Service {
 protected:
  // This class should be treated as an abstract interface.
  inline InstallService() {};
 public:
  virtual ~InstallService();

  typedef InstallService_Stub Stub;

  static const ::google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor* descriptor();

  virtual void getWifiNetworks(::google::protobuf::RpcController* controller,
                       const ::WifiRequest* request,
                       ::WifiResponse* response,
                       ::google::protobuf::Closure* done);

  // implements Service ----------------------------------------------

  const ::google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor* GetDescriptor();
  void CallMethod(const ::google::protobuf::MethodDescriptor* method,
                  ::google::protobuf::RpcController* controller,
                  const ::google::protobuf::Message* request,
                  ::google::protobuf::Message* response,
                  ::google::protobuf::Closure* done);
  const ::google::protobuf::Message& GetRequestPrototype(
    const ::google::protobuf::MethodDescriptor* method) const;
  const ::google::protobuf::Message& GetResponsePrototype(
    const ::google::protobuf::MethodDescriptor* method) const;

 private:
  GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(InstallService);
};

class InstallService_Stub : public InstallService {
 public:
  InstallService_Stub(::google::protobuf::RpcChannel* channel);
  InstallService_Stub(::google::protobuf::RpcChannel* channel,
                   ::google::protobuf::Service::ChannelOwnership ownership);
  ~InstallService_Stub();

  inline ::google::protobuf::RpcChannel* channel() { return channel_; }

  // implements InstallService ------------------------------------------

  void getWifiNetworks(::google::protobuf::RpcController* controller,
                       const ::WifiRequest* request,
                       ::WifiResponse* response,
                       ::google::protobuf::Closure* done);
 private:
  ::google::protobuf::RpcChannel* channel_;
  bool owns_channel_;
  GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(InstallService_Stub);
};
```

Comment: Why `Java` tag for this question?

Comment: I started with Java and i'm having BlockingImpl in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that no blocking code is generated by `protoc` so i had to use self-made blocking:

```
bool callbackFired = false;

void myCallback() {
    // ...
    callbackFired = true;
}

// run service method
service->myMethod(rpcController, request, response, NewCallback(&myCallback));

// block the thread until callback is invoked
while (!callbackFired);

...
```

C++ client usage example: https://github.com/4ntoine/protobuf-socket-rpc

Answer (score -1):

The way you do this is to provide your own subclass of InstallService that overrides the methods you want to implement:

```
struct MyInstallService : public InstallService
{
    void getWifiNetworks(::google::protobuf::RpcController* controller,
                       const ::WifiRequest* request,
                       ::WifiResponse* response,
                       ::google::protobuf::Closure* done) override
  {
    // do your work here

    // fill up the response here

    done->Run();  // this will trigger the response
  }
};
```

client side:
Something like this

```
namespace detail {
template<class F>
struct simple_closure : google::protobuf::Closure {

    simple_closure(F f)
    : _f(std::move(f))
    {}

    void Run() override {
        _f();
    }
private:
    F _f;
};
}

template<class F>
std::unique_ptr<detail::simple_closure<F>> make_closure(F&& f) {
    return std::make_unique<detail::simple_closure<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
}

std::unique_ptr<WifiResponse> syncGetWifiNetworks(InstallService_Stub & stub, const WifiRequest& req)
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<WifiResponse>();
    auto promise = std::promise<std::unique_ptr<WifiResponse>>;
    auto future = promise.get_future();
    auto controller = allocate_controller(); // you need to write this
    auto closure = make_closure([&result, &promise]{
        promise.set_value(std::move(result));
    });
    // assumes you already have an async comms queue - otherwise just 
    // dispatch this lambda to a std::async(std::launch::async, ...)
    comms_queue.dispatch([&controller, &req, &stub, &response]{
        stub.getWifiNetworks(controller, &req, response.get(), closure);
    };

    // HERE is where the current thread blocks until the promise is fulfilled
    return future.get();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be hacky way to get blocking. I'd prefer to have RPC-like (synchronous) interface instead if async, like i have in Java.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. do you want synchronous (blocking) interfaces or asyncronous (non-blocking)? Both are possible.

Comment: `Wifi.WifiResponse response = service.getWifiNetworks(controller, request);` is blocking (= synchronous), i'm already having async in C++ with Callback (`::google::protobuf::Closure* done`), now i need blocking interface in C++ like in Java (see above)

Comment: You simply implement blocking calls in terms of async ones. You can do that with a template that (for example) hands off to a std::async

Comment: From server-side point of view, you're right but you forget about client-side. I **dont want to deal with callback** (invocation like `getWifiNetworks( ... , callback)`), but i want `networks = getWifiNetworks(...)`. In Java BlockingInterface is generated but in C++ it's not generated for some reason.

Comment: you can implement synchronous in terms of asynchronous on the client side. I'll knock up a small example

Comment: i know one can make async from sync (using thread) and vice versa (block until callback is invoked). Why you're suggesting not to do the things the way they expect to be? Blocking interface **IS** generating in Java, why not in C++?? I there a way to generate it or i there is no way?

Comment: If the current generator is not to your liking, you can extend or replace it: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/other

Comment: is it a bug or a feature? I can't see any reason to have different implementations behaviour in Java and C++ so i believe it's a bug. Or there is a way to do it?

Comment: firstly, downvoting my answer because you don't like google's interface is a little unfair :-) Secondly, it's because google protocol buffers was written long before there was standardised threading in c++ (that came in c++11). So its neither a bug or a feature, it's just the way it is.

Comment: firstly, avoiding to solve the problem is not the solution. if the answer is "it's not implemented in C++ generator" i will create workaround myself (to block the thread until callback is invoked in order to do it synchronous). otherwise i'd prefer to do the things the way they should be done instead of reinventing the wheel